# An Iron Fist villain from the 1970s (maybe still current) who wants to absorb/steal the power of the Iron fist technique?

Tags: story-identification, marvel, iron-fist

**Summary/Plot**

I remember reading an Iron Fist comic in the late 1970s where Iron Fist (Danny Rand) squares off against a similarly-clad opponent.  This enemy has a similar mask and skin-tight outfit as I.F., though his outfit is blue (IIRC).  He also has a tattoo on his chest, but it is different than I.F.'s

Iron Fist channels the power of his Iron Fist to his enemy's delight, who grasps him and holds him against his chest tattoo.  Fist says/thinks something about his Chi being drained, and collapse unconscious.  The villain leaves him alive, but says something about how he wants the Iron Fist power for himself.

I don't know if this guy was a one-off, or a recurring foe (didn't read many Iron Fist comics).

**Time/Date of Publication**  Late 70s to 1980, no later, I think.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're most certainly talking about the Steel Serpent. He was introduced in 1975 only. Being able to drain the power of the Iron Fist from its wielder is the most notable ability in his power set.

[image: Steel Serpent]

This happened in the *Marvel Team-Up Vol. 1* #64 (1977).

[image: Issue 64 with Spider-Man recapping the fight between Iron Fist and Steel Serpent]

Comment: I've added the relevant panel from the comic I believe. Note though that it is a summary from a prior issue. However, nice find!